# What does the ^= selector in jQuery do?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I was reading some code on JSfiddle and I found this bit of code

```
 $('[name^="checkbox"]').change(function(event) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
             $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
        }
        else {
             $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('selected');
    });
```

Does someone know what `^=` means?

Comment: RTFM http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Check this**

Attribute Starts With Selector `[name^="value"]`

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   beginning exactly with a given string.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`. The W3C CSS
>   specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS
>   selectors. Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on CSS
>   character escape sequences for identifiers.